# Is there a way to prevent the Chrome extension from popping up on version update?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sequence/kcpganeflmhffnlofpdmcjklmdpbbmef). I noticed that when I upgrade a version it pops up on all existing users' browser. This is annoying because not all the update is critical.

I think this starts happening only recently. Is there a way to disable this or change the default behaviour to only slightly update the version?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it. But many users have reported that it is like the user clicked the icon to open the extension in a new tab. I can also see from Google analytics that the last two times when I publish a new version there is a peak traffic with short session.

Comment: Theoretically, you are intentionally doing this. But we need code, of course. What about your `onInstalled`, `onUpdateAvailable`, `onBrowserUpdateAvailable` events?

Comment: I thought Google might have recently changed the way to push new versions.

Comment: @DanielMöller I will update the code in the question tomorrow morning. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks a lot. It turns out that I am listening to the `onInstalled` event and open the app on update. This is a fork of another extension. It must have been brought in by merging their changes. If you could put that in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, usually the extensions don't popup automatically. Somewhere in your code there is probably something actively calling the popup.

I suggest you start looking into one of these events:

- onInstalled
- onUpdateAvailable
- onBrowserUpdateAvailable